# #1146 - Table 'database.table' doesn't exist with join?

Tags: mysql, database, join, sql-update, sql-insert

I've been in the process of copying data from my main database to a test database so I can become familiar with how it works for when I need to move columns between tables in the main database. Currently, I can `INSERT` new rows without a problem using this query.

```
INSERT INTO testDB.category_to_website (category_01_id)
SELECT t4.id
FROM testDB.websites t2
JOIN mainDB.websites t3 ON t2.url = t3.url
JOIN testDB.category_01 t4 ON t3.category2 = t4.name
WHERE t2.url = t3.url
```

But I can't come up with an equivalent `UPDATE` query for the existing rows. I'm trying this, but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE category_to_website
JOIN websites t2 ON t2.url = mainDB.websites.url
JOIN mainDB.websites t3 ON t2.url = t3.url
JOIN category_01 t4 ON t3.category2 = t4.name
SET t4.id=category_01_id
WHERE t2.url = t3.url
```

The problem, is here: `mainDB.websites.url`. I can't specify `database.table.column` because it results in `#1146 - Table 'mainDB.websites' doesn't exist`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please list test_DB.category_to_website fields?

Comment: Only field I need to update is `category_01_id`.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing the correct JOIN it is impossible. There is no join between the table to update and the others. Also there is a bit confusion with tables aliases

Comment: @kiks73 The fields are: `id`, `url_id`, `category_main_id`, `category_01_id`-`category_06_id`.

Comment: I've found a solution to this, but if someone can answer it you'll get the reputation. Clue: the answer is in the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I just answered. Since your solution can help someone, why not post it as an answer eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several major issues with this query contributing to the `#1146 - Table 'mainDB.websites' doesn't exist` error.

```
UPDATE category_to_website
JOIN websites t2 ON t2.url = mainDB.websites.url
JOIN mainDB.websites t3 ON t2.url = t3.url
JOIN category_01 t4 ON t3.category2 = t4.name
SET t4.id=category_01_id
WHERE t2.url = t3.url
```

**Issue #1:** When using `JOIN`, you've got to make sure that your identifiers are within scope.

```
JOIN websites t2 ON t2.url = mainDB.websites.url
```

At this point in the query, I haven't joined the `mainDB.websites` table so I can't use it as an identifier.

**Issue #2:** You can't mix aliases with fully qualified table references/identifiers.

Notice that `testDB.websites` is now `t2`, since I used an alias I can't use the `database.table` syntax anymore.

In order to fix this query, I had to change the identifiers in this `JOIN` to tables within the `testDB` since that's where the query was originating. I also had to remove the aliases or use them for all the table references/identifiers. Once you use an alias for a table, MYSQL is expecting you to use them completely. For this example, we will remove the aliases.

```
UPDATE category_to_website
JOIN websites
ON websites.id = category_to_website.url_id
JOIN category
ON category.name = websites.category1
SET category_to_website.category01_id = category.id
```

Also, as @philipxy has pointed out, the `WHERE` clause is also redundant and not needed. Here is the [MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) which explains the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE     testDB.category_01 t4 
INNER JOIN mainDB.websites t3 ON t4.name = t3.name
INNER JOIN testDB.websites t2 ON t2.url = t3.url
INNER JOIN testDB.category_to_website t1 on t1.category_01_id = t3.id
SET        t4.category_to_website = category_01_id
WHERE      t2.url = t3.url
```

Comment: I changed the updated field. But I'm still not sure about the last join

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't4.category_to_website' in 'field list'.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand in which table category_to_website is

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE testDB.category_to_website t1
JOIN testDB.websites t2
JOIN mainDB.websites t3 ON t2.url = t3.url
JOIN testDB.category_01 t4 ON t3.category2 = t4.name
SET t1.category_01_id = t4.id
```

The WHERE t2.url = t3.url in your INSERT is redundant. The FROM already creates a conceptual cross join that is ON-restricted to rows where t2.url = t3.url. A WHERE t2.url = t3.url would be redundant in this UPDATE too. The SET happens to t1 rows that participate in the ON-restricted cross join. Those are rows where t2.url = t3.url.

Answer (score -1):

```
Update t4 set t4.id=t6.category_01_id from testDB.category_01 t4 as t4     
 inner join  testDB.websites t2 ON t2.url = mainDB.websites.url
 inner join mainDB.websites t3 ON t2.url = t3.url
inner join testDB.category_01 t5 ON t3.category2 = t5.name
 inner join  testDB.category_to_website t6 on t4.ID=t6.category_01_id
  WHERE t2.url = t3.url
```

Comment: @Dhaval you have a syntax issue. It should be `update table_name t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id set t1.somecol = t2.some_col where t1.somecol = 'something'`

Comment: It doesn't like the `FROM`.

Comment: The problem is in line 1.